# How to create a new db in ImmenseDB?

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

I have installed ImmenseDB. Now I want to create a new database.

How can I create a new database in ImmenseDB?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a new db by using ImmenseDB **command-line interface(CLI)**.

First **connect** to ImmenseDB using below command.

```
ImmenseDB >> connect -u <user> -p <password> -h <host> -p <port>
```

Then run below **command** to **create** a new db

```
ImmenseDB >> create db <db name>
```

You can create db using JAVA connector also. Connect ImmenseDB from java program using ImmenseDB-java-jdbc-connector and run above command using execute method.

Comment: Is there have any other way to create db or execute commands? Is there have any admin client?